# Error When Renaming My Username

Tags: support, profile-page, email, accounts, display-names

I am trying to change my username. However, when I click the save button on my profile page, it returns the following error message:
[image]

I am already logged in! I also tried recovering my account, but it did not help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The critical requirement of renaming your name is to first drop in and see what condition your condition is in.

In this case, your condition is that of having two accounts with the same email address. Normally, the system would just merge those accounts, but in this case it wasn't confident enough to do so.

Being just chock full of confidence myself, I took care of the merge. You should now be able to change your username.